# Is (A v C) v B in conjunctive normal form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I need **T** to be a set of clauses in conjunctive normal form.

> T = {  (¬A ^ ¬C) → B  }
>   T = {  ¬(¬A ^ ¬C) v B }
>   T = {  (A v C) v B    }

I 'simplified' it to **T = { (A v C) v B }**, is it in **CNF**?

The formula has only disjoint symbols so my first impression is it isn't but since it can't be formulated with a conjunction it must be in **CNF**?

Comment: Yes, it is in CNF. It is also in DNF.  It is traditional to leave out the parentheses.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. I should have said that even though it is technically not correct to do so, it is traditional to leave out parentheses.